# Doctrine generates incorrect SQL when combining aggregate fields (group by) and ordering (order by) in a query with Paginator

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine, twig, doctrine-query

I have a simple bi-directional one-to-many relationship between `Item` and `Valoracion` (a review). The following query should get the average score and number of reviews for each Item, in descending order:

```
$itemsQb = $em->getRepository(Item::class)->createQueryBuilder('i')
    ->select('i as data')
    ->addSelect('avg(v.score) as avg_score')
    ->addSelect('count(v.score) as num_reviews')
    ->leftJoin('i.valoraciones', 'v')
    ->groupBy('i.id')
    ->addOrderBy('avg_score', 'DESC')
    ->addOrderBy('num_reviews', 'DESC');
```

where `$em` is a working `Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager` instance. When paginating the above mentioned query with `Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Pagination\Paginator` and traversing the results using `getIterator()` an exception is thrown, as follows:

```
$pag = new Paginator($itemsQb);

// first page, up to three results per page
$pag->getQuery()->setFirstResult(0)->setMaxResults(3);

// display results one by one
echo "Name\t\tAvg\tNum\n";
foreach ($pag->getIterator() as $p) {
   echo $p['data']->name . "\t" . $p['avg_score'] . "\t" . $p['num_reviews'] . "\n";
}
```

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #5 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'test.v1_.score' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

The following SQL query was generated

```
SELECT DISTINCT
id_5
FROM
(SELECT DISTINCT
    id_5, sclr_2, sclr_3
FROM
    (SELECT 
    i0_.id AS id_0,
        i0_.name AS name_1,
        AVG(v1_.score) AS sclr_2,
        COUNT(v1_.score) AS sclr_3,
        v1_.score AS score_4,
        i0_.id AS id_5
FROM
    item i0_
LEFT JOIN valoracion v1_ ON i0_.id = v1_.item_id
GROUP BY i0_.id) dctrn_result_inner
ORDER BY sclr_2 DESC , sclr_3 DESC) dctrn_result
LIMIT 3
```

where it's obvious that the line `v1_.score AS score_4,` should't be there at all!

So, why is this invalid SQL being generated? Am I doing something wrong?

**Notes:**

- If using `getQuery()->getResult()` instead of `getIterator()` everything works fine. I am still asking for help as Twig *apparently* uses `getIterator()` behind the `for` loop when `$pag` is passed to the template.
- If the `ORDER BY` clauses are removed, everything works fine too!
- I am using MySQL 5.7.25, `sql_mode=ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` and I DON'T want to change it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, you do not fetch the joined "to-many collection", you group by the **Item id** and just aggregate values of the "**valoraciones**" relation.

According to [doctrine pagination documentation](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/tutorials/pagination.html#pagination), in this case you can ***disable the $fetchJoinCollection flag***:

```
$pag = new Paginator($itemsQb, false);
```

It seems the issue is caused by doctrine trying to add the "missing fields" from the order by condition to the select clause. [Related issue](https://github.com/doctrine/orm/issues/4846)  [Pull request](https://github.com/doctrine/orm/pull/6143)

In this case, it thinks it should add "v.score" to the select.

Alternatively, you could disable the use of output walkers in the paginator to avoid the above behavior:

```
$pag->setUseOutputWalkers(false);
```

Comment: Initializing paginator with `$fetchJoinCollection = false` did the trick! The iterator now works perfectly.

Comment: As a side-note: In Twig, apparently if iterating through the result of `getQuery()->getResult()`, while it contains the current page elements, the `loop` variables will contain unexpected values;  `loop.length` will give the total number of elements instead of the element count for the current page; and `loop.last` will not be true for the last element of the collection, not for the last element of the page.

Comment: Thanks! The issue you mentioned says that it should be fixed in 2.7 but the error is still here.